# Angular 2 - Undefined when try to get the value from select

Tags: angular

I'm new on Angular 2 and i have this problem. I have a select with 3 options and i cannot get the value of one of this options.

> The html:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="product_type" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="getType()">           
        <option [ngValue]="A"><span>ALL</span></option> 
        <option [ngValue]="T"><span>Type product</span></option>
        <option [ngValue]="E"><span>Standart product</span></option>            
    </select>
```

> Component.ts:

```
 type_product:string;
/*...*/
 getType(){
   this.type_product= ""+this.type_product;
  console.log(this.type_product);

}
```

When i execute it, the log shows undefined. What i'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OjKybDnwqVvYxuBFWk5o?p=preview

Comment: That works! Than you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `[]` means you are trying to bind a variable, which you do not have, so besides the fact, that it shouldn't be `[ngValue]`, which is used for binding a non-string value, it shouldn't be `[value]` either, but `value`.

Also, two-way-binding `[(ngModel)]="product_type"` actually basically equals the following:

```
[ngModel]="product_type" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
```

so choose either version.

Here is how your code could look like:

```
<select [ngModel]="product_type" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="getType($event)">           
  <option value="A"><span>ALL</span></option> 
  <option value="T"><span>Type product</span></option>
  <option value="E"><span>Standard product</span></option>            
</select>
```

and ts:

```
getType(event){
  this.product_type= ""+event;
  console.log(this.product_type);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/OjKybDnwqVvYxuBFWk5o?p=preview)**

PS, and yes, as pointed out by others, your naming convention does not match:

`product_type` vs `type_product`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `value` instead of `[ngValue]` and `this.product_type` in the log function.

**[Demo plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KTkvpmmhvHrbIQaJxSvG)**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="product_type" class="form-control">
    <option value="A">ALL</option>
    <option value="T">Type product</option>
    <option value="E">Standard product</option>
</select>

<p>Selected value: {{product_type}}</p>
```

Comment: I tried to change and nothing, it does not work either

Comment: It's `value` without brackets, because you're not using an `*ngFor` bound to a variable from the component, but hardcoded values instead. Can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

You are naming differently:

Declaration:

```
[(ngModel)]="product_type"
```

Referenced:

```
this.type_product
```

Fix: Change one or another and get consistency :)

Comment: -.- It's true, but the problem continues

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need two-way data-binding:

```
    <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let i of devices">{{i}}</option>
    </select>

onChange(deviceValue) {
    console.log(deviceValue);
}
```

For two-way data-binding, separate the event and property bindings:

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedDevice" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="sel2">
    <option 
[value]="i" *ngFor="let i of devices">{{i}}</option>
    </select>
    export class AppComponent {
      devices = 'one two three'.split(' ');
      selectedDevice = 'two';
      onChange(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
        this.selectedDevice = newValue;
        // ... do other stuff here ...
    }
```

Comment: This way I already tried it and neither, it continues coming out undefined

Comment: @Aw3same can you have a plunker for the same

Comment: @Aw3same AJT_82 posted a plunker with the same approach as mine

Comment: Is not the same, i just remove te "[]" from tag  [value] and all it's ok! But thak you for your time!